# “As can I.“ Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: inversion

I know English has inversion features. And So does my first language.

> She can speak Swahili and so can I.

— this sounds totally correct.

Then how about using as instead of so:

> She can speak Swahili and as can I.

— this sentence reads little kind of strange though. regarding “as do I.” is grammatically correct, what do you say about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence "She can speak Swahili and as can I." is grammatically incorrect.  You have two conjunctions in this sentence: "and" and "as".  By removing the "and", the sentence becomes proper:

> She can speak Swahili as can I.

In your first example, "so" is not being used as a conjunction, it's being used to mean "too", so it's fine.

Comment: Sweet! Your very answer  makes sense, thank you.